# Hilbert space self adjoint and idempotent

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, idempotents, self-adjoint-operators

> A linear operator $P: H \to H$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is self-adjoint if for every $f, g \in H$, $\langle Pf, g\rangle=\langle f,Pg\rangle$ and is idempotent if for every $f \in H$, $P(P(f))=P(f)$ (i.e. $P^2=P$).  Show that if $P$ is self-adjoint and idempotent then it is continuous with $\|P\|= 0$ or $1$ and that $Pf \perp (f-Pf)$ for any $f \in H$.

I'm not sure on things from Hilbert space other that I need  =  but I don't how to start or do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that it suffices to show $P$ is bounded for continuity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! As part of the rules of the site, we require that you provide some of your thoughts/attempts in solving problems. I understand that you don't know how to start, but do you know how to express $Pf \perp (f - Pf)$ using inner products? How about $\|P\| = 0$ and $\|P\| = 1$? Under what circumstances do we have $\|P\| = 0$? Whatever tidbits of information you know is helpful for us to gauge your level, and help us find exactly what you need explaining. Without this information, your question may be down-voted and/or closed.

Comment: Here are some basic definitions for solving a problem like this:

1. We say a linear transformation $P$ from $H \to H$ is bounded if there exists an $M$ such that for all $h \in H$, we have $\|P(h)\| \le M\|h\|$. Recall that $\|h\|^2 = \langle h,h \rangle$.

2. For $h \in H$, define $\|P\| = \inf M$ for $M$ as defined above. 

3. As mentioned by Dave, there is a theorem that states a linear operator between Hilbert spaces is bounded $\iff$ it is continuous. 

4. Lastly, for $f,g \in H$, recall $f \perp g$ means $\langle f,g\rangle = 0$. 

This should help get you started.

Comment: So I think the ||P||=0 is the nothing need to show.  I found the argument for ||P||=1 by a double inequality trick and I know that Pf $\perp$ (f-Pf) = 0 but I don't know why. and I don't know what Dave means by bounded for continuity.

Answer (score 3):

In situations like this (i.e., basic questions) it often pays just writing the definitions.  To check that $P$ is bounded, you need to find a constant $c$ such that $\|Px\|\leq c\|x\|$ for all $x$. So we write $\|Px\|$ and we use what we know about $P$:
$$
\|Px\|^2=\langle Px,Px\rangle=\langle P^*Px,x\rangle=\langle P^2x,x\rangle=\langle Px,x\rangle\leq \|Px\|\,\|x\|.
$$
If $\|Px\|\ne0$, you get $\|Px\|\leq \|x\|$, showing that $P$ is bounded and $\|P\|\leq1$. For any $x$ in the range of $P$, you have $x=Py$ for some $y$, so
$$
Px=P^2y=Py=x.
$$
Then $\|Px\|=\|x\|$ for such $x$, which shows that $\|P\|\geq1$.
You can also get $\|P\|\geq1$ from $\|P\|=\|P^2\|\leq\|P\|^2$.

To show the orthogonality condition, again you just write what you need: for two things to be orthogonal, you need their inner product to be zero. Now
$$
\langle Px,y-Py\rangle=\langle P^2x,y-Py\rangle=\langle Px,P^*(y-Py)\rangle=\langle Px,P(y-Py)\rangle=0. 
$$